# Можно ли импортировать отдельные функции из .js файла?

Tags: javascript, ajax

У меня есть 2 .js файла: *mainPage.js и questionTab.js*

В первом жс файле есть большой метод, который заполняет список.

```
function fillQuestionBlock(q) {
let questionData =
    '<li class="list-group-item">' +
        '<div class="question-block container mt-4">' +
            '<div class="voice-block">' +
                '<div class="voices voice-item">' +
                    '<p class="points">' + q.countValuable + '</p>' +
                    '<span class="smallHeader">Голосов</span>' +
                '</div>' +
 ////
```

И мне нужно воспользоваться этим методом со второго файла,чтоб избежать неприятной большой дублированности.
Можно ли импортировать данный метод ? или мб есть другие альтернативные варианты

Comment: Вам не удастся получить адекватный ответ на вопрос, состоящий из одной строчки текста, из которой невозможно понять, что Вы хотите сделать и в чем заключается трудность. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1147641/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b0%d1%8f%d0%ba%d1%81-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не знаю, что Вы называете словами "большой метод", но если это глобальная функция, то она видна везде на странице, так что Вы можете просто ее вызывать.

Comment: просто относительно объемный метод, т.е который содержит от 15-20 строчек. Извините меня за мой французский. Я жавист, поэтому вместо слово функция, я использую  - "метод"

Comment: Видимо ТС питонист, раз он так импорты понимает.

Comment: а можно,пожалуйста, пояснить слово глобальная функкция

Comment: @NursD Вы уже сделали поиск на "javascript global function"?

Comment: @NursD https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29514382/global-functions-in-javascript